# How do I get my prompt value to append to a unordered list using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to get a prompt value to attach to an unordered list and I cannot seem to get it to work.

My button is:

```
<button onclick="nameP()">PLEASE CLICK</button>
```

Here is my jQuery/Java code:

```
function nameP() {
var name = prompt("Please enter your name"); 
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = name;
$('#a').appendTo('ul')}
```

my unordered list is

```
<ul></ul>
```

thank you for any help

Comment: How is it not working? Are there any errors? What is `#a`?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the value from the anchor tag, that i'm not sure what it contains. But the code below will work as you want. It will take the name from the prompt box and then append that text to the unordered list

```
function nameP() {
  var name = prompt("Please enter your name"); 
  $('ul').append(name)
}
```